# How to fix vault error: failed to read request counters: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I worked with hasicorp's vault for some months.
After my Windows had a restart in the night, I am not longer able to unseal my vault, because of the following error message (after giving the third/last unseal key):

> Error unsealing: Error making API request.
>
> URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/unseal
>
> Code: 500. Errors:
>
> - failed to read request counters: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because of the restart I looked for corrupted files and found one at:

> [...]\vault\sys\counters\requests\2019\

within this directory there are files named like:

> _04
>
> _05
>
> _06

When these files are ok, their content looks like:

> {"Value":"AAAAAQK[....]"}

But one of these was filled with \x00 values instead.

After deleting this file, unsealing works again - so problem solved.

Comment: This worked for me on windows 10 (version 20H2 build 19042.662) and vault 1.6.4 amd64bit